# Conflict when inserting data into a table contains 2 PK

Tags: sql-server-2008, conflict

I have 3 tables with the connection as follow:

```
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/41645335.jpg/
```

and my stored procedure to enter data to this table as below:

```
@tutor_id as varchar(20),
@module_id as varchar(20)


INSERT INTO tutor_module(tutor_id, module_id) VALUES(@tutor_id, @module_id);
```

with data provided to the 2 variables from the form when the user click button "ADD"

But when I call the stored procedure, I met this problem: 
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tutor_module_module". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\DUCTRIEU\DESKTOP\DROPBOX\G20547722\APP_DATA\G20547722DB.MDF", table "dbo.module", column 'module_id'.
The statement has been terminated."

Can any one please let me know how to insert data into this table without making mistake?
The data format for them are varchar(20).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert a value for `module_id` that doesn't exists on the `module` table, that's the whole point of foreign keys. This will sound very obvious, but to avoid that mistake you first need to make sure that the values for both `tutor_id` and `module_id` exist on the `tutor` and `module` tables respectively

Comment: the variable "@tutor_id" contains data sent from the web form.
the variable "@module_id" contains the data selected from the module table. And the two tables Tutor and Module already contains their own data.

Comment: @user2180317 Well, then there is an error in the retrieval of the value for `@module_id`, since it's trying to insert a value that doesn't exist on the table `module`, that's what the error is saying. Can you modify your statement to look what value is actually trying to insert?

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. The format of the module_id in the module table is BN0001 but I tried to insert /BN0001.